# Nodejs scalable file upload server

Tags: node.js, multer-s3

Multer supports memory storage and disk storage
My objective is to upload file to s3 through my node server.

But Multer has this warning message in the documentation.

Uploading very large files, or relatively small files in large numbers very quickly, can cause your application to run out of memory when memory storage is used.

My application will be used my many people and there will be simultaneous multiple file uploads will be happening.

Should i use memory storage or disk storage to temporarily store buffer and push to s3 from there?

Comment: When you use file uploader it will first save the file in default locations (some /tmp etc.). Once you get the request of file upload, you will get the path of temporary folder, now you can save this file name and with a separate process, you can upload the files to s3.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Minio (an s3 compatible file upload server).
You should visit below urls to get started with minio:- 
https://docs.min.io/
https://github.com/minio/minio-js